# Python GTK3 button with image and label

Tags: python, image, button, label, gtk3

I'm trying to get buttons with image and label and didn't succed. I can have button with label OR image but not both.
This is my part of code:

```
try:
    pb = Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_size('myimg.jpg', 100, 100)
except:
    pb = None
img = Gtk.Image()
img.set_from_pixbuf(pb)
button1 = Gtk.Button(xalign=0.5, yalign=1)
#button1.set_label(lbl)
button1.set_image(img)
button1.set_image_position(Gtk.PositionType.TOP)
button1.get_style_context().add_class("btn_article")
```

any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doc: Gtk.Button.set_image (widget, data): "The image will be displayed if the label text is NULL". The image here usually is an icon, therefore there is a icon-name associate with it and  (depends on settings) if necessary showing the label according the icon. Reverse the situation, the label is used to find an icon associate with it and (if necessary) showing the icon.
Use:

```
button1.set_always_show_image (True)
```

or, if that doesn't succeed, create a container inside (in your case Gtk.Grid) and pack inside the button, i.e:

```
grid = Gtk.Grid ()
img = Gtk.Image()
img.set_from_pixbuf(pb)
label = Gtk.Label ('test')

grid.attach (img, 0, 0, 1, 1)
grid.attach (label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
grid.show_all ()    

button1.add (grid)
```

Comment: I am using ruby but the python syntax works almost 1:1. The .set_always_show_image(true) seems to have worked just fine. I actually ended up using a horizontal box though - was easier to wrap my mind around it as opposed to a grid.

Comment: Nah in my case `set_always_show_image` will indeed hide the label again. So creating a container with a label + image would be the only way.