# Clickable Icon in Python GTK

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Does anyone know how to create a custom button with custom icon in PyGTK?
 I would like to make a program in python GTK that works similar to a settings menu or control panel.  I know PyGTK has stock buttons like cancel, exit, and ok; but I'm unable to change the labels or icons of those buttons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python GTK3 button with image and label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658123/python-gtk3-button-with-image-and-label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a button on the screen, and put any image in it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  test_icon.py
#  
#  Copyright 2015 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  

import pygtk
import gtk

IMAGE_FILE = "/put/an/imagename here"

class MainWindow(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, debug = None):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect("delete-event", self.on_delete_event)

        btn = gtk.Button()
        img = gtk.Image()
        img.set_from_file(IMAGE_FILE)
        btn.set_image(img)

        self.add(btn)
        self.show_all()

    def on_delete_event(self, win, data):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def run(self):
        gtk.mainloop()

def main():
    w = MainWindow()
    w.run()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The image can be of many formats, even SVG (vector graphics), PNG, etc.

Comment: Add on to the answer, since this topic is regarding icon which meant to have same height and width using `img = Gtk.Image()        
icon = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_size(path_to_image, 32, 32)
img.set_from_pixbuf(icon)
button.set_image(img)` gives you more control over the size of the image being displayed in the button